# Solve the following set of equations using Laplace Transforms

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, laplace-transform

The two equations are $$y''+z''-z'=0$$ $$y'+z'-2z = 1-e^{-t}$$ where $y_0 =0 , z_0 = 1$,  $y'_0\text{ and } z'_0 = 1$
I've found that $$L(y') = pL(y)-y_0$$ $$L(y'') = p^2L(y)-py_0-y'_0$$
$$L(1-e^{-t}) = \frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{p+1}$$
Which gives the set of equations
$$p^2L(y)-1+p^2L(z)-p-1-pL(z)+1=0$$ $$pL(y)+pL(z)-1-2L(z)=\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{p+1}$$
From here I'm unsure how to solve for $y$ and $z$. How do I calculate the inverse Laplace transform after solving this set of equations? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Subtract $\frac{1}{p}$ times the first equation from the second, and then you get an equation in terms of only $L(z)$. Then you can plug that into the top equation to get $L(y)$. Once you have those you will get a rational function for both, so just find the residues and become a glade freshener(plug it in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following system of equations in $L(y)$ and $L(z)$:
\begin{eqnarray}
pL(y)+(p-1)L(z)&=&\dfrac{1}{p}+1\\
pL(y)+(p-2)L(z)&=&\dfrac{1}{p}-\dfrac{1}{p+1}+1
\end{eqnarray}
Subtracting the first and second equations we get
$$
L(z)=\dfrac{1}{p+1},
$$
then substituting $L(z)$ into the first equation we get
\begin{eqnarray}
pL(y)+\dfrac{p-1}{p+1}&=&\dfrac{1}{p}+1\\
pL(y)&=&\dfrac{1}{p}+1-\dfrac{p-1}{p+1}\\
pL(y)&=&\dfrac{1}{p}+\dfrac{2}{p+1}\\
L(y)&=&\dfrac{1}{p^2}+\dfrac{2}{p(p+1)}\\
L(y)&=&\dfrac{1}{p^2}+\dfrac{2}{p}-\dfrac{2}{p+1}.
\end{eqnarray}
Hence
\begin{eqnarray}
y(t)&=&tu(t)+2u(t)-2e^{-t}u(t)=(t+2-2e^{-t})u(t)\\
z(t)&=&e^{-t}u(t)
\end{eqnarray}
with $u$ the unit step function, i.e.
$$
u(t)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } t<0\\
1 & \text{ if } t \ge 0
\end{cases}.
$$